How do programs like GoodRX make money?
There are a variety of prescription discount card programs; I use GoodRX only as an example but my question applies to them all.
How do these things make money?
My local pharmacy just keeps a couple of discount cards at the register, and if a prescription is particularly expensive they'll ask if I want to try a discount card.  Recently one of these cards brought a prescription down from $700+ to ~$22.  I suppose GoodRX gets some amount of demographic info about me when I use the card but can they really make hundreds of dollars off of that info???  I just don't see where there's a viable revenue stream.

This is not really a question about Personal Finance.

Hi Crash Gordon. Welcome. Please note that this site deals with personal finance. I expect that your question will be closed as off-topic.

As a side note, the drug probably costs nowhere near $700 to source, so they don't have to make all of that up using demographic info or whatever other revenue streams they may tap.

These are US-centric programs. In the US, the medicine prices are extremely inflated compared to the actual costs (including amortized R&D costs), as such they provide huge profit margins for the brokers. GoodRX is one such broker and is acting on arbitrage. They still have margins, just smaller than the competition.

@Tashus knowing how they make their money lets a person understand their risks when using them. Do I need to pay a monthly fee? Do I need to register? Do I have to only use generics?

@mhoran_psprep: Valid personal health questions. Personal Finance, I'm less sure. But I don't know whether there's a better place to ask about health costs/insurance/etc.

Here is a comment from the  perspective of Medicare beneficiaries. Some of these at-the-checkout-counter plans are actually full-fledged Medicare Part C programs, and accepting their coupon enrolls the beneficiary in their Part C program, thereby terminating the beneficiary's current Part C coverage  (if any) or the beneficiary's Original Medicare coverage, plus Medigap policy, if any. So, the elderly should be aware of this.

@mhoran_psprep Those questions could apply to literally any business. How a certain business model generates revenue is not personal finance.

@keshlam: There are some questions where there is no site on the stackexchange network where that question is on-topic.  This may be one of them.

Nothing's off topic at reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/pharmacy/comments/twfgh8/how_do_discount_cards_work/?rdt=54320

At a big picture "economics" level, this (like most weird behavior you see in consumer markets) is a form of "price discrimination" (i.e. finding a way to make people who are willing and able to pay a higher price do so, while making additional profits from selling at a lower price to people who aren't willing and able to pay the higher price in a way that excludes those who are willing and able to pay the higher price most of the time).

Nothing's off topic at reddit. If this is to be believed, https://www.reddit.com/r/pharmacy/comments/twfgh8/how_do_discount_cards_work/?rdt=54320

the PBMs (Pharmacy Benefits Manager, a.k.a. 800 billion dollar trio of gorillas in the pharmaceutical industry) contractually require pharmacies to charge $700 for prescriptions, then offer it at the realistic price of $22 to their (the PBM's) customers' (typically health insurance providers) customers (insureds).
The same PBMs then offer a discount card program to let non-customers get the discount too.
Why? Because then the PBM gets to charge fees to the pharmacy as clawbacks/DIR Fees for the privilege of inserting themselves into the transaction. For example, fees can be as high as $8.50 for the $22 prescription.


I think John Oliver has an episode on that. It's amazing what Americans take for granted that is absolutely bonkers to anyone else.

What does PBM stand for? Online search didn't give me any useful.

@quarague Pharmacy Benefit Manager.

It's less that we take it for granted, and more that we are all stuck in a terrible system.

@aslum There's some "chicken vs. egg" there. We're stuck in it because many people think it's normal, e.g. having to pay for health care. Free health care is considered "socialism", but few say the same thing about free K-12 education.

@Barmar Fair enough - though part of the problem is probably how many people just have a knee jerk "socialism is bad" reaction without knowing what it actually means.

@aslum There's almost certainly a "socialism == communism == bad" assumption involved for many people. And Republicans are happy to perpetuate this.
